# Kanji with rearranged components but with different meaning

Tags: kanji

There are numerous 異体字 where the relation between the two characters is just a different arrangement of all the parts. For instance 裏/裡, 群/羣, 胸/胷, 棋/棊...

Are there instances where a simple re-arrangement of parts results in a change in meaning?

Comment: As worded, there won’t be an end to the number of possible answers to this question - anyone can pull examples from the top of their head (here: 集 and 椎) if they think hard enough. Are you looking for something more concrete, e.g an *explanation*, or are you just looking for a list?

Comment: I couldn't come up with a concrete example where the components are actually the same etymologically wise/the difference in meaning isn't just a Japanese oddity.

For instance: 集 is actually the abridged form 雧. 累 is the abridged form of 纍 whilst 細 is the corruption . The difference of 脇/脅 is only seen in Japanese, 脇 is in reality just a 異体字 with the same naming.

Comment: Ohh, but 忘 and 忙 is not a Japanese oddity either, the different word usage it represents was inherited from Chinese. Also, out of the examples you just listed, 集 actually has the same components as 椎, it’s just that two of the three birds in 雥 were removed. There is actually no 田 in 累 or 細. Interesting tibit about 脇 and 脅 though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [忙](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%BF%99) and [忘](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%BF%98) (忄 is left-side variant of 心.)

---

The following pairs are not 異体字 from historical point of view, but in modern forms they appear in this way:

- [泊](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%B3%8A) and [泉](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%B3%89) (氵 is left-side variant of 水.)
- [員](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%93%A1) and [唄](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%94%84) (Origin of 唄 is unknown, while lower part of 員 is simplification of ancient form of 鼎.)

Comment: Thank you, that is a very simple and concrete example. This led me to a very interesting article by [漢字文化資料館](https://kanjibunka.com/kanji-faq/jitai/q0082/)